# Wrong result calculation Hour angle from altitude azimuth

Tags: javascript, math, coordinate-systems, astronomy

I am making a Javascript program and on of the functions is to convert altitude/azimuth to right-ascension/declination given a time and latitude. My code can find the declination fairly accurately, I checked with Stellarium. I have been using [this](http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/%7Efv/webnotes/chapter7.htm) site to help me with the math.

My program gives me the wrong value for horizontal ascension which I plan on using to find right ascension (I already have a function to find local sidereal time which works). Here is my code for the equation
`var ha = asin(-sin(az)*cos(alt) / cos(dec)) * (180 / Math.PI);` this code is in Javascript but I defined custom sin/cos/asin functions that take degrees as input and return radians because that is the form my data is in.

The site I use also says that this equation should give the same result
`var ha = acos((sin(alt) - sin(lat)*sin(dec)) / (cos(lat) * cos(dec))) * (180 / Math.PI);`
but, the two equations give different results and neither are correct according to stellarium. I have checked that all the variables I am putting in are correct and I am almost certain I entered the equation correct. [Here](https://github.com/Blank2275/AstroCoordsJS/blob/master/index.js) is the full code on github. I need help figuring out how to fix this problem.
--Note this can be run with node js with no libraries
The result I get is { ra: [ 23, 57, 37.9 ], dec: [ -5, 24, 38.88 ] }
It should be getting { ra: [ 5, 36, 22.6 ], dec: [ -5, 24, 38.88 ] it does not have to be exact, I only really care about the first number of ra (right ascension). It is also formatted in HMS format. The datetime is hardcoded to Febuary 1st 2022 12:00:00 so that is what you should set [stellarium](https://stellarium-web.org/) to if you are testing this out. 
Here is the relevant code

```
function altazToradec(alt, az, lat, lon, time){
    /*
    right ascension (α)
    declination (δ)
    altitude (a)
    azimuth (A)
    siderial time (ST)
    latitude (φ) (Φ)
    */
    var lst = getLST(time, lon);
    var dec = asin(sin(lat)*sin(alt) + cos(lat)*cos(alt)*cos(az)) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var ha = asin(sin(az)*cos(alt) / cos(dec)) * (180 / Math.PI);//acos((sin(alt) - sin(lat)*sin(dec)) * (sec(lat) * sec(dec))) * (180 / Math.PI);//acos((sin(alt) - sin(lat)*sin(dec)) / (cos(lat)*cos(dec))) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var ra = lst - ha;
    console.log(ha)
    return {
        "ra": ra,
        "dec": dec
    }
}
```

Here are some more test cases

```
console.log(altazToradecHms(-34.6825, 63.7814, 40.5853, -105.0844, new Date('February 1, 2022 12:00:00').getTime()))// Ft. Collins Co M42 Orion nebula Feb 1st 2022 12:00 noon
console.log(altazToradecHms(-34.6825, 63.7814, 41.875, -87.624, new Date('January 1, 2022 08:00:00').getTime()))//Chicago M42 Orion nebula Jan 1st 2022 8:00 AM
console.log(altazToradecHms(301.7678, 64.41758, 51.49, -0.14, new Date('February 1, 2020 12:00:00').getTime()))//London Eta Cas Feb 1st 2020 12:00 noon
```

which returns

```
{ ra: [ 23, 57, 37.9 ], dec: [ -5, 24, 38.88 ] }
{ ra: [ 19, 4, 59.25 ], dec: [ -6, 16, 33.68 ] }
{ ra: [ 5, 59, 37.02 ], dec: [ -31, 34, 55.6 ] }
```

instead of

```
{ ra: [ 5, 36, 22.7], dec: [ -5, 22, 44 ] }
{ ra: [ 5, 36, 22.7 ], dec: [ -5, 22, 40.3 ] }
{ ra: [ 0, 50, 25.7 ], dec: [ 57, 56, 4.7 ] }
```

Note: I have checked and I also believe the getLST() function works, I have checked it.
Thank you - CR.

Comment: The input data is in degrees? Why not do the entire calculation in either degrees or radians. Only convert the one to the other after all the calculations are done.

Comment: I kind of wish you posted the code here instead of a link to GitHub.  If there is too much code to post here then it's likely not a _minimal_ reproduction of your problem. Since it's JavaScript and not dependent on any libraries, you could even make it a runnable snippet.

Comment: I convert the result of the asin to degrees after the calculation at the end of the line by multiplying by (180 / Math.PI). It is round about in retrospect and I may change it in the future but the whole system works in the othe function radectoaltaz

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of valid input with the corresponding expected outputs?

Comment: Also the time format...what time format are you using? Are you sure that it corresponds to the time that you are expecting the system to use? Timezones and localization can be tricky to get right.

Comment: After more testing, it only works if the date is in the same timezone as the lon so I will have to fix that

Comment: Two things at a glance. One, could there be an issue working with floats vs decimals? Second, the order of operations might be a challenge. When I have gnarly equation in JS, I sometimes break the operations into smaller pieces, assign results to variables and then use those variables in the larger equation. One benefit of that is you can log the steps and see if you can find where the numbers are deviating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try.  Notable changes include:

- Specified 'GMT+0000' when establishing J2000.0 date, in addition to the date being passed in to `altazToradec()`.  Otherwise, new Date() returns local time.
- Sourced calculation of 'DEC' and 'HA' from [MathWorks.com](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24581-convert-azimuth-and-elevation-to-right-ascension-and-declination) (look under the "Functions" tab).
- NOTE:  'HA' and 'RA' are in degrees, not hours.  To convert to hours, multiply by (24 hrs / 360 deg), or simply divide by (15 deg / hr).
- Sourced sample data from [StarGazing.net](http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/altaz.html#twig04).

```js
function deg2rad( x ) { return x * Math.PI / 180 };
function rad2deg( x ) { return x * 180 / Math.PI };

function sinDeg( x ) {
  return Math.sin( deg2rad( x ) );
}

function cosDeg( x ) {
  return Math.cos( deg2rad( x ) );
}

function asinDeg( x ) {
  return rad2deg( Math.asin( x ) );
}

function atan2Deg( y, x ) {
  return rad2deg( Math.atan2( y, x ) );
}

// getLST copied from https://github.com/Blank2275/AstroCoordsJS/blob/master/index.js
// and then tweaked.

function getLST(time, lon){
    //time = new Date(time)
    const J2000Date = new Date('January 1, 2000 12:00:00 GMT+0000').getTime();
    const diff = time - J2000Date;
    const d = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    var hours = time.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = time.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getUTCSeconds();
    var ms = time.getUTCSeconds();
    var utc = (hours * (1000 * 60 * 60) + minutes * (1000 * 60) + seconds * 1000 + ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 360;//(now.getTime() - beginning.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 360;
    var lst = 100.46 + (0.985647 * d) + lon + utc;
    if(lst > 360){
        while(lst > 360){
            lst -= 360;
        }
    } else if(lst < 0){
        while(lst < 0){
            lst += 360;
        }
    }
    return lst;
}

// Equations sourced from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24581-convert-azimuth-and-elevation-to-right-ascension-and-declination

function altazToradec( alt, az, lat, lon, time ){
    /*
    right ascension (α)
    declination (δ)
    altitude (a)
    azimuth (A)
    siderial time (ST)
    latitude (φ) (Φ)
    */
    var lst = getLST( time, lon );
    var dec = asinDeg( sinDeg( alt ) * sinDeg( lat ) + cosDeg( alt ) * cosDeg( lat ) * cosDeg( az ) );
    var ha = atan2Deg(
      -sinDeg( az ) * cosDeg( alt ) / cosDeg( dec ),
      ( sinDeg( alt ) - sinDeg( dec ) * sinDeg( lat ) ) / ( cosDeg( dec ) * cosDeg( lat ) )
    );
    var ra = ( lst - ha ) % 360;

    return {
        "ha": ha,
        "ra": ra,
        "dec": dec
    }
}

// See example from http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/altaz.html#twig04

console.log( 'Input:  ALT = 49.169122, AZ = 269.14634, LAT = 52.5, LON = 0, Date = 2310 UT on 10th Aug 1998' );
console.log( 'Expected Output:  HA = 54.382617, DEC = 36.466667' );
x = altazToradec( 49.169122, 269.14634, 52.5, 0, new Date('August 10, 1998 23:10:00 GMT+0000') );
console.log( x );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that looks like it will work

Comment: @connorfrancis oddly enough, i spent more time looking for solid sample data.  i found an Alt/Az => Ha/Dec calculator online, but could not produce any results with which i felt comfortable...  i see you added some new sample data, and hopefully the tweaks i proposed are proven out by these samples...